# <ToggleButton> onClickListener - changing drawable back to default

Tags: java, android, onclick, togglebutton

I've got this ToggleButton which is supposed to change the drawables (and functions) of some other buttons upon toggling on/off.

So far i've only managed to make it work one way, by using this code.

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.bRedGreen);
    toggle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            minuskugle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bBallhole);
            minuskugle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.redballinhole);

        }

    });
}
```

How do you make it change the drawable back to default upon another click?

***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_***

This works for one entry.

However if i add multiple entries it comes with an error for the "else".

**This works:**

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            pluskugle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bBallhole);
            minuskugle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bBallhole);

            pluskegle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bKegle);
            minuskegle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bKegle);

        if(toggle.isChecked())
            minuskugle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.redballinhole);
        else
            pluskugle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.whiteballhole);
```

**This doesn't**

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            pluskugle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bBallhole);
            minuskugle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bBallhole);

            pluskegle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bKegle);
            minuskegle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bKegle);

        if(toggle.isChecked())
            minuskugle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.redballinhole);
            minuskegle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.redkegle);
        else
            pluskugle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.whiteballhole);
            pluskegle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.redkegle);
```

Comment: wtf are you doing ? setBackgroundResource for the same button twice?

Comment: It's not the same button, read closely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.bRedGreen);
    toggle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            minuskugle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bBallhole);
            if(toggle.isChecked())
               minuskugle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.redballinhole);
            else
               minuskugle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.xy);


        }

    });
}
```

Comment: You forgott the{} brackets. So you have to write: if(...){...}else{…}

Answer (score 1):

*dummy solution*

Keep a boolean somewhere to save the state

```
boolean isPressed = false;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.bRedGreen);
    toggle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            minuskugle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bBallhole);
            if(!isPressed)
                minuskugle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.redballinhole);
            else
                minuskugle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yourotherdrawable);
            isPressed = !isPressed;
        }
    });
}
```